# gcc: quickly check for all errors but not compile C?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, static-analysis

I want to check for all syntax & semantic errors in the flow while not wasting time on waiting it to compile every time.

1. Is it possible with compiler architecture that gcc uses?
2. If possible, how?

Comment: gcc manages replacable front-ends (to support compiling of multiple languages) as well as replacable back-ends (to support code generation for multiple platforms, and specifically cross-platform compiling). So, theoretically, it should be possible to use a "null-backend" which would result in compiling the code (with all diagnostics as usual) just without creating a binary output. May be, such back-end already exists but I don't know. "quick"... Yeah... `gcc` is IMHO not slower than other C++ compilers I know but is this quick enough?

Comment: Sounds like you need something like intellisense that MSVS offers.  I believe VS code offers that if you are on linux.

Comment: I mean raw compilation speed, in my experience it lags behind something like tcc.

Comment: Use flag `-fsyntax-only`

Comment: @Mansoor does it report type errors, printf etc warnings & casting warnings etc..?

Comment: @Mansoor Found the doc. side: [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options): _Check the code for syntax errors, but don’t do anything beyond that._ If taken literally, semantic checks would be excluded... (Although, I find it sounds promising.)

Comment: I got at least some warnings with [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72b2b2bedc11649e).

Comment: There seems to be a dupl. (which recommends `-fsyntax-only` as well): [SO: Compile without generating output file in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26738152/7478597) and a comment which recommends `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O -c somefile.c -o /dev/null` instead. Not the "null-backend" but just throwing any generated code away... ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I modified your demo a bit: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49bf0f5f59890070). The syntax-only run seems really to skip some of the things diagnosed in ful compile.

Comment: The `-S` option generates assembler; is that stopping soon enough?

Comment: Well, you can rarely check for *semantic* errors even in compiled program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile without generating output file in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738082/compile-without-generating-output-file-in-gcc)

Comment: If it takes longer than 1 second for you to compile a single source file, then the problem is not the compiler. The problem is your IDE, or your computer or your LAN. Or less likely, you have a horrifically huge source file. In either case, not a compiler problem.

Comment: @Lundin The codegen step can be surprisingly expensive.  Both in terms of i/o and in terms of actual generation.  I noticed a massive speedup in the compile step when enabling lto for a project, which led me down the path of looking for a "syntax-only" mode.

Answer (score 7):

GCC has a `-fsyntax-only` flag which checks for syntax errors, see [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).